# Incorrect paragraph.style property after changing revision view

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to ascertain information about the revisions within my users' word documents, but my VBA code does not seem to return the correct paragraph.style property when I change the revision view.

From what I can tell, it looks like the .style property is 'playing catchup' and is not reflecting the expected value when the script is ran in real time, and I do see the expected value when pausing on the print line in debug mode. Perhaps there is a way to ensure that the revision view change 'settles' before running the next line in my code? I have tried multiple instances of DoEvents but to no avail.

One can reproduce the behavior I am seeing by doing the following:

1. Create/modify a document to have the first paragraph be style=Heading1 and the second paragraph is style=body.
2. Turn on track-changes and delete the heading paragraph, then also add a partial-paragraph revision to the body paragraph (insertion or deletion).
3. Run this subroutine from within that document:

   ```
   Sub test()

       For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
           ActiveDocument.Windows(1).View.RevisionsFilter.Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupNone
           Debug.Print "STYLE: [" & rev.Range.Paragraphs(1).Style & "], TEXT: [" & rev.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range & "]"
           ActiveDocument.Windows(1).View.RevisionsFilter.Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupAll
       Next rev

   End Sub
   ```

You will see that the debug print out will incorrectly show 'heading 1' for the style or both of the first revisions (the deleted heading and the revision in the second paragraph). I.e. I believe that the style should show 'Body' for both of these revisions. This is based on my examination of the state of the document and the revision range when I pause the code in debug more on the 'print.debug' line, as well as the 'text' output that gets printed in all cases.

And I will just add here that my 'flanking' of view changes in each loop is a valid and useful mechanism to employ, as my actual full code does a lot more stuff inside of this for-loop and thus I wanted this style-read to be 'atomic' and 'revert' the view state after I do the read. Ultimately the point is that: what I want to do should 'work', even if there is likely a more efficient way to organize things.

Comment: Which version of Word is this? Word 2010 doesn't recognize the `Markup` property...

Comment: FWIW I commented out the `Markup` lines and tested. The code worked as expected with "Final showing markup" as the display setting; it worked more or less the way you describe when the markup is not displayed. In that case, not only is the style Heading 1 for both revisions, the text is always the text of the entire non-deleted paragraph, even for the deleted revision. I disagree with the assertion "I believe that the style should show 'Body' for both of these revisions."...

Comment: ...And I would assert that having Revisions visible in order to process them is how Word is designed to be used. In the UI it's not possible to move to a Revision (except in the Pane) if they are not visible - you get an error message.